# Compute multiple model properties in one call

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have Django Model which has two properties:

```
class M(Model):

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return process_result(SomeModel.objects.filter(val_gt=1))

    @property
    def p2(self):
        return process_result(SomeModel.objects.filter(val_lt=1))
```

And both used in Django Admin `list_lisplay = ('p1','p2',)`
I want to replace 2 database queries with 1, something like this

```
class M(Model):

    def some_hook(self): 
        res = SomeModel.objects.all()
        self.p1 = process_result(filter(lambda l:l.val > 10, res))
        self.p2 = process_result(filter(lambda l:l.val < 10, res))
```

PS: problem with `>10 or <10` is just an example for simplification, I am only trying to find a way how to define **multiple properties** with performing **one common database query**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to cache your queryset result in model:

```
class M(Model):

    def get_some_model(self):
        attr_name = '_some_model_cache'
        if hasattr(self, attr_name):
            return getattr(self, attr_name)
        qs = SomeModel.objects.all()
        setattr(self, attr_name, qs)
        return qs

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return process_result(filter(lambda l:l.val > 10, self.get_some_model()))

    @property
    def p2(self):
        return process_result(filter(lambda l:l.val < 10, self.get_some_model()))
```

Comment: Thanks! I also thought about it, do you have any idea how to reset this cache when user reloads the page in admin? (I want to cache it only for one-page render)